# how arranges the components in frame with using miglayout? ( java ) ( swing project )

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent, miglayout

I have two radio buttons in frame. When I click to "Manuel Server" (at the right bottom corner) I want to put a text box instead of radio buttons. When click to "MANUEL Server" again I want to put radio buttons instead of textBox again. Now I can only put text box near radio buttons. I can not put instead of them(upon them). How should set it?

[Before click to Manuel_Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5spjP.png)

[After click to Manuel_Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0idF.png)

```
    jconnectManuelServer = new JLabel("<html><u>" + ELanguage.getString("Manuel_Server") + "</u></html>");
        jconnectManuelServer.setVisible(true);

        jconnectManuelServer.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (!loginClicked) {

                    jconnectAutomatic = new JLabel("MANUEL_Server");
                    jconnectAutomatic = new JLabel("<html><u>" + ELanguage.getString("MANUEL_Server") + "</u></html>");
                    jconnectManuelServer.setVisible(false);
                    jserverOptLive.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 1));
                    jserverOptDemo.setContentAreaFilled(true);
                    jserverOptDemo.setVisible(false);
                    jserverOptLive.setVisible(false);
                    jconnectAutomaticText.setVisible(true);
                    panel.remove(jconnectManuelServer);
                    panel.add(jconnectAutomatic, "width 3:150:140,wrap");
                    jconnectAutomatic.setVisible(true);

                    jconnectAutomatic.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            jconnectAutomatic.setVisible(false);
                            panel.remove(jconnectAutomatic);
                            panel.add(jconnectManuelServer);
                            jconnectManuelServer.setVisible(true);
                            jconnectAutomaticText.setVisible(false);
                            jserverOptDemo.setVisible(true);
                            jserverOptLive.setVisible(true);

                        }
                    });

                }

            }

        });

    private void loadComponent() {
        // add components to panel here

        panel.add(new JLabel(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.esse.trader.loginframe.login")),
                "newline 50,gap 150");
        if (userList == null || userList.length < 2) {
            panel.add(jlogin, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "width 1:150:150,wrap");
        } else {
            panel.add(juserCombo, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "width 1:150:150,wrap");
        }
        panel.add(new JLabel(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.esse.trader.loginframe.password")), "gap 150");
        panel.add(jpass, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "width 1:150:150,wrap");
        panel.add(new JLabel(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.esse.trader.loginframe.server")), "gap 150");
        //panel.add(server, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "width 1:150:150,wrap");

            panel.add(jserverOptLive, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "width 1:60:60, split 2");
            panel.add(jserverOptDemo, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "width 1:60:60,split 3");


        panel.add(jconnectAutomaticText, "width 1:100:200, wrap");
        jconnectAutomaticText.setVisible(false);

//        panel.add(new JLabel(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.esse.trader.loginframe.port")), "gap 150");
//        panel.add(jport, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "width 1:100:80,split 3");
        panel.add(new JLabel(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.esse.trader.loginframe.ssl")), "gap 150");
        panel.add(juseSsl, "wrap");
        if (TClientExe.setupType != 1) {
            panel.add(new JLabel(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.esse.trader.loginframe.language")), "gap 150");
            panel.add(jlanguage, "width 1:80:150,wrap");
        }
        panel.add(new JLabel(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.esse.trader.loginframe.save")), "gap 150");
        panel.add(jsaveCredentials, "width 1:30:25, split 2");
        panel.add(jdeleteSavedUser, "wrap");
        panel.add(jloginButton, "gap 150");

        panel.add(jcancelButton, /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "wrap");

        panel.add(TClientExe.getProgressBar(), /*LANG_IGNORE*/ "w 100:100,span,growx,wrap,gap 150");
        if (TClientExe.setupType != 1) {
            panel.add(jcreateNewDemoAccount);
            panel.add(emptyLabel);
            panel.add(jconnectManuelServer);
        }
        setResizable(false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple. You should have a panel which should be of card layout.

- Place holder ( panel - with card layout) will have two panels inside

  - First Panel ( which contains two radio buttons )
  - Second Panel ( which contains the text box )

On click on the Manual Server you can switch the cards.

Hope this would be helpful.